# why im unable to authenticate other users except the super user in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have used the default `path('',include("django.contrib.auth.urls"))` in django to perform login,password reset operations for my project,I have thoroughly checked my signup form and the database,everything goes well with the registration part,but I am unable to authenticate all other users except the super user,what might be the reason for this issue?

```
myproject/urls.py:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('home.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('',include("django.contrib.auth.urls"))
]
```

and in templates in registration directory my login form will look like

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

my signup view is:

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = RegForm
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid()):
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

And then then my form:

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields=['first_name','last_name','username','email','date_joined','password','confirm_password']
    def clean_password(self):
        password=self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        if(len(password)<8):
            raise forms.ValidationError("The length of the password should be minimum 8 characters")

        return password
    def clean_email(self):
        email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if(validate_email(email)==False):
            raise forms.ValidationError("The Email Format is In Correct")
        return email
    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        if (password != confirm_password):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password doesn\'t match')
```

Comment: for other user check `is_active` set to `True` or not?

Comment: yeah i have set that,but stil having the same problem @ShafikurRahman

Comment: Does it show an error? more details are needed

Comment: You need to show some code. How are you creating the users? How are you authenticating then? Show the sign-up and login forms and views.

Comment: It  as continuously showing the error," Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.",

Comment: i have given more information now to my question,i hope i will find a solution:)

Comment: you are not saving the user you need to do this inside after form.is_valid(): `user = form.save(commit=False)` and then set a password `user.set_password(password)` and finally save the user `user.save()`

Comment: Thank you so much @Ahtisham, i have fixed it,now its working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments you need to save the user like this:

```
 def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: yeah!! Thank you :);)

Answer (score 1):

Django expects the `password` field of the `User` model to contained a hashed password. Your form stores the password in plaintext (which is a big security no-go).

I suggest you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.5/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L65) of [`django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) on how to properly create a user.

Edit: my guess is that you can sign in with the superuser because you created it with the `createsuperuser` command.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you incorrectly save the password. In django it perform a hashing over the password. You either use the django User password field( ref link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.password) so your RegForm looks like

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):

    confirm_password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields=['first_name','last_name','username','email','date_joined','password','confirm_password']
    def clean_password(self):
        password=self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        if(len(password)<8):
            raise forms.ValidationError("The length of the password should be minimum 8 characters")

        return password
    def clean_email(self):
        email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if(validate_email(email)==False):
            raise forms.ValidationError("The Email Format is In Correct")
        return email
    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        if (password != confirm_password):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password doesn\'t match')
```

Or

save the hashed value of input passwor in the post method. So the code look like

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid()):
        user_form = form.save(commit=False)
        user_form.set_password(request.POST.get('password'))
        user_form.save()
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```